# Groovy object retrieval using String notation

Tags: groovy

Writing a utility method for Jenkins pipeline using groovy and noticed its not easy to get value from a deeply nested map using externalised object retrieval notation as string.

Question: If you see the example below, you will notice that its not possible to retrieve object in the form datas."bankctrl.deployment.clientConfigMap.enabled". You definitely can do datas."bankctrl"."deployment"."clientConfigMap"."enabled". I have a workaround, but question is if there is any known best approach to do this?

```
datas = [
    "ao":[
        deployment:[
            clientConfigMap:[
                enabled:"true", name:"volume-ao-custom"
            ], image:[
                name:"test/mit/ao", 
                tag:"10.0.0-3.0.0", 
                pullPolicy:"IfNotPresent"
            ]
        ]
    ], "bankctrl":[
        deployment:[
            clientConfigMap:[
                enabled:"false", 
                name:"volume-bankctrl-custom"
            ], image:[
                name:"test/mit/bankctrl", 
                tag:"10.0.0-3.0.0", 
                pullPolicy:"IfNotPresent"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]

String name = "bankctrl"
datas."${name}".deployment.clientConfigMap.enabled = true

println datas

//following does't work as dots within string are not evaluated.
String elementNameToUpdate = "bankctrl.deployment.clientConfigMap.enabled"
datas."${elementNameToUpdate}" = true
```

Following code works when you need to access values using externalised string:

```
String s = "bankctrl.deployment.clientConfigMap.enabled"

def q = s.split( /\./ ).inject( datas ) { obj1, prop -> obj1?."$prop" }

println q
```

Even this works when you need to access values using externalised string:

```
String s = "bankctrl.deployment.clientConfigMap.enabled"
Eval.x(datas,"x.${s}")
```

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: How to make the following to work. Notice that elementNameToUpdate is string instead of dot notation.

String elementNameToUpdate = "bankctrl.deployment.clientConfigMap.enabled"
datas."${elementNameToUpdate}" = true

Comment: Use eval.me - what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

```
def gpathSet = { obj,path,value -> Eval.xy(obj, value, "x.${path}=y") }

datas = [
    "bankctrl":[
        deployment:[
            clientConfigMap:[
                enabled:"false", 
                name:"volume-bankctrl-custom"
            ], image:[
                name:"test/mit/bankctrl", 
                tag:"10.0.0-3.0.0", 
                pullPolicy:"IfNotPresent"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]

String elementNameToUpdate = "bankctrl.deployment.clientConfigMap.enabled"
gpathSet(datas, elementNameToUpdate, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of workaround.

```
String s = "bankctrl.deployment.clientConfigMap.enabled"

def setDeepProps(s,datas, value) {

    s.split(/\./).inject(datas) {
        obj, prop ->
            if (obj."$prop" instanceof Map)
                obj?."$prop"
            else
                obj."$prop" = value
    }
}

setDeepProps(s,datas,true)

println datas
```

Answer (score 0):

Groovy doesn't have this functionality out-of-box, so you have to either go wild and use `Eval` :) which for this certain case is a bit fragile (if the path-string is misspelled it can produce RuntimeExceptions) and not the best performer (due to run-time compilation).

You can solve your problem with a simple recursion like so:

```
def datas = [
    "ao":[
        deployment:[
            clientConfigMap:[
                enabled:"true", name:"volume-ao-custom"
            ], image:[
                name:"test/mit/ao",
                tag:"10.0.0-3.0.0",
                pullPolicy:"IfNotPresent"
            ]
        ]
    ], "bankctrl":[
        deployment:[
            clientConfigMap:[
                enabled:"false",
                name:"volume-bankctrl-custom"
            ], image:[
                name:"test/mit/bankctrl",
                tag:"10.0.0-3.0.0",
                pullPolicy:"IfNotPresent"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]

def traverser

traverser = { map, path ->
  int ix = path.indexOf '.'
  if( -1 == ix ) return map[ path ]
  
  def val = map[ path[ 0..<ix ] ]
  if( val in Map )
    traverser val, path.substring( ix + 1 )
  else
    null
}

traverser datas, "bankctrl.deployment.clientConfigMap.enabled"
```

Answer (score 0):

Below workaround worked for me. The reason I preferred this over any other solution is cause Jenkins is very picky about what script you invoke and hence wanted to have a work around that would not force me to accept script execution in Jenkins while getting around this requirement.

On a side note, would have loved if Jenkins would let me explore full power of Groovy and unfortunately it doesn't because of security reasons.

```
datas = [
    "ao":[
        deployment:[
            clientConfigMap:[
                enabled:"false", 
                name:"volume-ao-custom"
            ], image:[
                name:"test/mit/ao", 
                tag:"10.0.0-3.0.0", 
                pullPolicy:"IfNotPresent"
            ]
        ]
    ], "bankctrl":[
        deployment:[
            clientConfigMap:[
                enabled:"false", 
                name:"volume-bankctrl-custom"
            ], image:[
                name:"test/mit/bankctrl", 
                tag:"10.0.0-3.0.0", 
                pullPolicy:"IfNotPresent"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]

boolean customConfigFolderExists = true
String elementNameToUpdate = "bankctrl.deployment.clientConfigMap.enabled"

String[] elementNameToUpdateArray = "${elementNameToUpdate}".split("\\.")
                                                        
def tempDatas = datas

//get property like datas.bankctrl.deployment.clientConfigMap (note that we are leaving enabled out which would be invoked in the following steps)
for (int i=0; i<elementNameToUpdateArray.length-1; i++) {
    println "elementNameToUpdateArray[i] -> ${elementNameToUpdateArray[i]}"
    tempDatas = tempDatas?."${elementNameToUpdateArray[i]}"
}

//we are invoking property returned from for loop above using the last element from elementNameToUpdateArray 
tempDatas?."${elementNameToUpdateArray[elementNameToUpdateArray.length-1]}" = true

println "datas = ${datas}"
```